# \nocite{*} not working while using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, errors

I am trying to list all references on a paper I am writing, however only the cited documents are appearing. I have placed a \nocite{*} at the end of my document, and it is able to generate my document. However, I get various errors such as 'Undefined control sequence.' and 'File `paper1.bib' already exists on the system.'

Can someone please help me address this issue and why I am having these errors occur? I have included my code below. These errors do not appear once I remove the \nocite{*} command and recompile.

Thanks.

```
\documentclass[12pt, american, titlepage]{article}
    \usepackage[style=apa, sortcites=true, sorting=nyt, hyperref=true, backend=biber, uniquelist=true, uniquename=false, natbib=true]{biblatex}
    \DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
    \usepackage[font={scriptsize, it}, justification=centering]{caption}
    \usepackage[UTF8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{multicol} % Used for the two-column layout of the document
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{subfigure}
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{csvsimple}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[citecolor=black, urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
    \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
    \usepackage{enumitem}


    \usepackage{fancyhdr}

    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \chead{\textbf{Course \\ Course}}
    \rhead{Date \\}
    \lhead{Name}
    \cfoot{\thepage}

    \usepackage{babel}

    \addbibresource{paper1.bib}

    \begin{filecontents*}{paper1.bib}

    @article{Boykoff2004,
        author = {Boykoff, Maxwell and Boykoff, Jules},
        title = {Balance as bias: global warming and the US prestige press},
        journaltitle = {Global Environmental Change},
        date = {2004},
        OPTtranslator = {translator},
        OPTannotator = {annotator},
        OPTcommentator = {commentator},
        OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
        OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
        OPTeditor = {editor},
        OPTeditora = {editora},
        OPTeditorb = {editorb},
        OPTeditorc = {editorc},
        OPTjournalsubtitle = {journalsubtitle},
        OPTissuetitle = {issuetitle},
        OPTissuesubtitle = {issuesubtitle},
        OPTlanguage = {language},
        OPToriglanguage = {origlanguage},
        OPTseries = {series},
        volume = {14},
        OPTnumber = {number},
        OPTeid = {eid},
        OPTissue = {issue},
        OPTmonth = {month},
        pages = {125-136},
        OPTversion = {version},
        OPTnote = {note},
        OPTissn = {issn},
        OPTaddendum = {addendum},
        OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
        OPTdoi = {doi},
        OPTeprint = {eprint},
        OPTeprintclass = {eprintclass},
        OPTeprinttype = {eprinttype},
        OPTurl = {url},
        OPTurldate = {urldate},
    }

    @article{Boykoff2007,
        author = {Boykoff, Maxwell and Boykoff, Jules},
        title = {Climate change and journalistic norms: A case-study of US mass-media coverage},
        journaltitle = {Geoforum},
        date = {2007},
        OPTtranslator = {translator},
        OPTannotator = {annotator},
        OPTcommentator = {commentator},
        OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
        OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
        OPTeditor = {editor},
        OPTeditora = {editora},
        OPTeditorb = {editorb},
        OPTeditorc = {editorc},
        OPTjournalsubtitle = {journalsubtitle},
        OPTissuetitle = {issuetitle},
        OPTissuesubtitle = {issuesubtitle},
        OPTlanguage = {language},
        OPToriglanguage = {origlanguage},
        OPTseries = {series},
        volume = {38},
        OPTnumber = {number},
        OPTeid = {eid},
        OPTissue = {issue},
        OPTmonth = {month},
        pages = {1190-1204},
        OPTversion = {version},
        OPTnote = {note},
        OPTissn = {issn},
        OPTaddendum = {addendum},
        OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
        OPTdoi = {doi},
        OPTeprint = {eprint},
        OPTeprintclass = {eprintclass},
        OPTeprinttype = {eprinttype},
        OPTurl = {url},
        OPTurldate = {urldate},
    }

    @report{GeorgeMasonUniversity2014,
        author = {Roser-Renouf, Connie and Maibach, Edward and Leiserowitz, Anthony and Feinberg, Geoff and Rosenthal, Seth and Kreslake, Jennifer},
        title = {Global Warming's Six Americas in October 2014: Perceptions of the Health Consequences of Global Warming and Update on Key Beliefs},
        type = {Research},
        institution = {George Mason University},
        date = {2014},
        OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
        OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
        OPTlanguage = {language},
        OPTnumber = {number},
        OPTversion = {version},
        OPTnote = {note},
        OPTlocation = {location},
        month = {October},
        OPTisrn = {isrn},
        OPTchapter = {chapter},
        pages = {1-42},
        OPTpagetotal = {pagetotal},
        OPTaddendum = {addendum},
        OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
        OPTdoi = {doi},
        OPTeprint = {eprint},
        OPTeprintclass = {eprintclass},
        OPTeprinttype = {eprinttype},
        OPTurl = {url},
        OPTurldate = {urldate},
    }

    @book{StudyingPublicPolicy,
        author = {Howlett, Michael and Ramesh, M. and Perl, Anthony},
        title = {Studying Public Policy: Policy Cycles and Policy Subsystems},
        date = {2009},
        OPTeditor = {editor},
        OPTeditora = {editora},
        OPTeditorb = {editorb},
        OPTeditorc = {editorc},
        OPTtranslator = {translator},
        OPTannotator = {annotator},
        OPTcommentator = {commentator},
        OPTintroduction = {introduction},
        OPTforeword = {foreword},
        OPTafterword = {afterword},
        OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
        OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
        OPTmaintitle = {maintitle},
        OPTmainsubtitle = {mainsubtitle},
        OPTmaintitleaddon = {maintitleaddon},
        OPTlanguage = {language},
        OPToriglanguage = {origlanguage},
        OPTvolume = {volume},
        OPTpart = {part},
        edition = {Third},
        OPTvolumes = {volumes},
        OPTseries = {series},
        OPTnumber = {number},
        OPTnote = {note},
        OPTpublisher = {publisher},
        OPTlocation = {location},
        OPTisbn = {isbn},
        chapter = {5, Agenda Setting: Policy Determinants, Policy Ideas and Policy Windows},
        pages = {120-142},
        OPTpagetotal = {pagetotal},
        OPTaddendum = {addendum},
        OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
        OPTdoi = {doi},
        OPTeprint = {eprint},
        OPTeprintclass = {eprintclass},
        OPTeprinttype = {eprinttype},
        OPTurl = {url},
        OPTurldate = {urldate},
    }

    @article{Bernabo1995,
        author = {Bernabo, Christopher},
        title = {Communication Among Scientists, Decision Makers and Society: Developing Policy-Relevant Global Climate Change Research.},
        journaltitle = {Climate Change Research: Evaluation and Policy Implications},
        date = {1995},
        OPTtranslator = {translator},
        OPTannotator = {annotator},
        OPTcommentator = {commentator},
        OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
        OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
        OPTeditor = {editor},
        OPTeditora = {editora},
        OPTeditorb = {editorb},
        OPTeditorc = {editorc},
        OPTjournalsubtitle = {journalsubtitle},
        OPTissuetitle = {issuetitle},
        OPTissuesubtitle = {issuesubtitle},
        OPTlanguage = {language},
        OPToriglanguage = {origlanguage},
        OPTseries = {series},
        OPTvolume = {volume},
        OPTnumber = {number},
        OPTeid = {eid},
        OPTissue = {issue},
        OPTmonth = {month},
        OPTpages = {pages},
        OPTversion = {version},
        OPTnote = {note},
        OPTissn = {issn},
        OPTaddendum = {addendum},
        OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
        OPTdoi = {doi},
        OPTeprint = {eprint},
        OPTeprintclass = {eprintclass},
        OPTeprinttype = {eprinttype},
        OPTurl = {url},
        OPTurldate = {urldate},
    }

    @report{UNReport2007,
        author = {Boykoff, Maxwell and Roberts, Timmons},
        title = {Media Coverage of Climate Change: Current Trends, Strengths, Weaknesses},
        type = {Research},
        institution = {United Nations Development Programme},
        date = {2007},
        OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
        OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
        OPTlanguage = {language},
        OPTnumber = {number},
        version = {Final},
        OPTnote = {note},
        OPTlocation = {location},
        OPTmonth = {month},
        OPTisrn = {isrn},
        OPTchapter = {chapter},
        OPTpages = {pages},
        OPTpagetotal = {pagetotal},
        OPTaddendum = {addendum},
        OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
        OPTdoi = {doi},
        OPTeprint = {eprint},
        OPTeprintclass = {eprintclass},
        OPTeprinttype = {eprinttype},
        OPTurl = {url},
        OPTurldate = {urldate},
    }

    @article{Leombruni2015,
        author = {Leombruni, Lisa},
        title = {How you talk about climate change matters: A communication network perspective on epistemic skepticism and belief strength},
        journaltitle = {Global Environmental Change},
        date = {2015},
        OPTtranslator = {translator},
        OPTannotator = {annotator},
        OPTcommentator = {commentator},
        OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
        OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
        OPTeditor = {editor},
        OPTeditora = {editora},
        OPTeditorb = {editorb},
        OPTeditorc = {editorc},
        OPTjournalsubtitle = {journalsubtitle},
        OPTissuetitle = {issuetitle},
        OPTissuesubtitle = {issuesubtitle},
        OPTlanguage = {language},
        OPToriglanguage = {origlanguage},
        OPTseries = {series},
        volume = {35},
        OPTnumber = {number},
        OPTeid = {eid},
        OPTissue = {issue},
        OPTmonth = {month},
        pages = {148-161},
        OPTversion = {version},
        OPTnote = {note},
        OPTissn = {issn},
        OPTaddendum = {addendum},
        OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
        OPTdoi = {doi},
        OPTeprint = {eprint},
        OPTeprintclass = {eprintclass},
        OPTeprinttype = {eprinttype},
        OPTurl = {url},
        OPTurldate = {urldate},
    }

    @article{Budeseu2009,
        author = {Budeseu, Stephen and Por, Han-Hui},
        title = {Improving Communication of Uncertainty in the Reports of the Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change},
        journaltitle = {Psychological Science},
        date = {2009},
        OPTtranslator = {translator},
        OPTannotator = {annotator},
        OPTcommentator = {commentator},
        OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
        OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
        OPTeditor = {editor},
        OPTeditora = {editora},
        OPTeditorb = {editorb},
        OPTeditorc = {editorc},
        OPTjournalsubtitle = {journalsubtitle},
        OPTissuetitle = {issuetitle},
        OPTissuesubtitle = {issuesubtitle},
        OPTlanguage = {language},
        OPToriglanguage = {origlanguage},
        OPTseries = {series},
        volume = {20},
        number = {3},
        OPTeid = {eid},
        OPTissue = {issue},
        OPTmonth = {month},
        pages = {299-308},
        OPTversion = {version},
        OPTnote = {note},
        OPTissn = {issn},
        OPTaddendum = {addendum},
        OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
        OPTdoi = {doi},
        OPTeprint = {eprint},
        OPTeprintclass = {eprintclass},
        OPTeprinttype = {eprinttype},
        OPTurl = {url},
        OPTurldate = {urldate},
    }

    @article{Weingart2000,
        author = {Weingart, Peter and Engels, Anita and Pansegrau, Petra},
        title = {Risks of communications: discourses on climate change in science, politics, and the mass media},
        journaltitle = {Public Understanding of Science},
        date = {2000},
        OPTtranslator = {translator},
        OPTannotator = {annotator},
        OPTcommentator = {commentator},
        OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
        OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
        OPTeditor = {editor},
        OPTeditora = {editora},
        OPTeditorb = {editorb},
        OPTeditorc = {editorc},
        OPTjournalsubtitle = {journalsubtitle},
        OPTissuetitle = {issuetitle},
        OPTissuesubtitle = {issuesubtitle},
        OPTlanguage = {language},
        OPToriglanguage = {origlanguage},
        OPTseries = {series},
        volume = {9},
        OPTnumber = {number},
        OPTeid = {eid},
        OPTissue = {issue},
        OPTmonth = {month},
        pages = {261-283},
        OPTversion = {version},
        OPTnote = {note},
        OPTissn = {issn},
        OPTaddendum = {addendum},
        OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
        OPTdoi = {doi},
        OPTeprint = {eprint},
        OPTeprintclass = {eprintclass},
        OPTeprinttype = {eprinttype},
        OPTurl = {url},
        OPTurldate = {urldate},
    }

    @article{Russill2009,
        author = {Russill, Chris and Nyssa, Zoe},
        title = {The tipping point trend in climate change communication},
        journaltitle = {Global Environmental Change},
        date = {2009},
        OPTtranslator = {translator},
        OPTannotator = {annotator},
        OPTcommentator = {commentator},
        OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
        OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
        OPTeditor = {editor},
        OPTeditora = {editora},
        OPTeditorb = {editorb},
        OPTeditorc = {editorc},
        OPTjournalsubtitle = {journalsubtitle},
        OPTissuetitle = {issuetitle},
        OPTissuesubtitle = {issuesubtitle},
        OPTlanguage = {language},
        OPToriglanguage = {origlanguage},
        OPTseries = {series},
        volume = {19},
        OPTnumber = {number},
        OPTeid = {eid},
        OPTissue = {issue},
        OPTmonth = {month},
        pages = {336-344},
        OPTversion = {version},
        OPTnote = {note},
        OPTissn = {issn},
        OPTaddendum = {addendum},
        OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
        OPTdoi = {doi},
        OPTeprint = {eprint},
        OPTeprintclass = {eprintclass},
        OPTeprinttype = {eprinttype},
        OPTurl = {url},
        OPTurldate = {urldate},
    }

    @inbook{Layzer2007,
        author = {Layzer, Judith},
        title = {Deep Freeze: How Business Has Shaped the Global Warming Debate in Congress},
        booktitle = {Corporate Interests in the American Political System},
        date = {2007},
        OPTbookauthor = {bookauthor},
        editor = {{M. Kraft and S. Kamieniecki}},
        OPTeditora = {editora},
        OPTeditorb = {editorb},
        OPTeditorc = {editorc},
        OPTtranslator = {translator},
        OPTannotator = {annotator},
        OPTcommentator = {commentator},
        OPTintroduction = {introduction},
        OPTforeword = {foreword},
        OPTafterword = {afterword},
        OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
        OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
        OPTmaintitle = {maintitle},
        OPTmainsubtitle = {mainsubtitle},
        OPTmaintitleaddon = {maintitleaddon},
        OPTbooksubtitle = {booksubtitle},
        OPTbooktitleaddon = {booktitleaddon},
        OPTlanguage = {language},
        OPToriglanguage = {origlanguage},
        OPTvolume = {volume},
        OPTpart = {part},
        OPTedition = {edition},
        OPTvolumes = {volumes},
        OPTseries = {series},
        OPTnumber = {number},
        OPTnote = {note},
        OPTpublisher = {publisher},
        OPTlocation = {location},
        OPTisbn = {isbn},
        chapter = {4},
        pages = {93-125},
        OPTaddendum = {addendum},
        OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
        OPTdoi = {doi},
        OPTeprint = {eprint},
        OPTeprintclass = {eprintclass},
        OPTeprinttype = {eprinttype},
        OPTurl = {url},
        OPTurldate = {urldate},
    }

    @article{Rabe2007,
        author = {Rabe, Barry},
        title = {Can Congress Govern the Climate?},
        journaltitle = {New York University’s John Brademas Center for the Study of Congress},
        date = {2007},
        OPTtranslator = {translator},
        OPTannotator = {annotator},
        OPTcommentator = {commentator},
        OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
        OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
        OPTeditor = {editor},
        OPTeditora = {editora},
        OPTeditorb = {editorb},
        OPTeditorc = {editorc},
        OPTjournalsubtitle = {journalsubtitle},
        OPTissuetitle = {issuetitle},
        OPTissuesubtitle = {issuesubtitle},
        OPTlanguage = {language},
        OPToriglanguage = {origlanguage},
        OPTseries = {series},
        OPTvolume = {volume},
        number = {1},
        OPTeid = {eid},
        OPTissue = {issue},
        OPTmonth = {month},
        pages = {1-14},
        OPTversion = {version},
        OPTnote = {note},
        OPTissn = {issn},
        OPTaddendum = {addendum},
        OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
        OPTdoi = {doi},
        OPTeprint = {eprint},
        OPTeprintclass = {eprintclass},
        OPTeprinttype = {eprinttype},
        OPTurl = {url},
        OPTurldate = {urldate},
    }

    @article{EMBO2007,
        author = {Boykoff, Maxwell and Rajan, Ravi},
        title = {Signals and noise: Mass-media coverage of climate change in the USA and the UK},
        journaltitle = {EMBO Reports},
        date = {2007},
        OPTtranslator = {translator},
        OPTannotator = {annotator},
        OPTcommentator = {commentator},
        OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
        OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
        OPTeditor = {editor},
        OPTeditora = {editora},
        OPTeditorb = {editorb},
        OPTeditorc = {editorc},
        OPTjournalsubtitle = {journalsubtitle},
        OPTissuetitle = {issuetitle},
        OPTissuesubtitle = {issuesubtitle},
        OPTlanguage = {language},
        OPToriglanguage = {origlanguage},
        OPTseries = {series},
        volume = {8},
        number = {3},
        OPTeid = {eid},
        OPTissue = {issue},
        OPTmonth = {month},
        pages = {207-211},
        OPTversion = {version},
        OPTnote = {note},
        OPTissn = {issn},
        OPTaddendum = {addendum},
        OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
        OPTdoi = {doi},
        OPTeprint = {eprint},
        OPTeprintclass = {eprintclass},
        OPTeprinttype = {eprinttype},
        OPTurl = {url},
        OPTurldate = {urldate},
    }

    @article{Oreskes2004,
        author = {Oreskes, Naomi},
        title = {The Scientific Consensus on Climate Change},
        journaltitle = {Science},
        date = {2004},
        OPTtranslator = {translator},
        OPTannotator = {annotator},
        OPTcommentator = {commentator},
        OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
        OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
        OPTeditor = {editor},
        OPTeditora = {editora},
        OPTeditorb = {editorb},
        OPTeditorc = {editorc},
        OPTjournalsubtitle = {journalsubtitle},
        OPTissuetitle = {issuetitle},
        OPTissuesubtitle = {issuesubtitle},
        OPTlanguage = {language},
        OPToriglanguage = {origlanguage},
        OPTseries = {series},
        volume = {306},
        OPTnumber = {number},
        OPTeid = {eid},
        OPTissue = {issue},
        OPTmonth = {month},
        pages = {1686},
        OPTversion = {version},
        OPTnote = {note},
        OPTissn = {issn},
        OPTaddendum = {addendum},
        OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
        OPTdoi = {doi},
        OPTeprint = {eprint},
        OPTeprintclass = {eprintclass},
        OPTeprinttype = {eprinttype},
        OPTurl = {url},
        OPTurldate = {urldate},
    }

    @article{Carlton2016,
        author = {Carlton, J. and Jacobson, Susan},
        title = {Using Expert and Non-expert Models of Climate Change to Enhance Communication},
        journaltitle = {Environmental Communication},
        date = {2016},
        OPTtranslator = {translator},
        OPTannotator = {annotator},
        OPTcommentator = {commentator},
        OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
        OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
        OPTeditor = {editor},
        OPTeditora = {editora},
        OPTeditorb = {editorb},
        OPTeditorc = {editorc},
        OPTjournalsubtitle = {journalsubtitle},
        OPTissuetitle = {issuetitle},
        OPTissuesubtitle = {issuesubtitle},
        OPTlanguage = {language},
        OPToriglanguage = {origlanguage},
        OPTseries = {series},
        volume = {10},
        number = {1},
        OPTeid = {eid},
        OPTissue = {issue},
        OPTmonth = {month},
        pages = {1-24},
        OPTversion = {version},
        OPTnote = {note},
        OPTissn = {issn},
        OPTaddendum = {addendum},
        OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
        OPTdoi = {doi},
        OPTeprint = {eprint},
        OPTeprintclass = {eprintclass},
        OPTeprinttype = {eprinttype},
        OPTurl = {url},
        OPTurldate = {urldate},
    }

    @article{Casado2014,
        author = {Casado-Asensio, Juan and Steurer, Reinhard},
        title = {Bookkeeping rather than climate policy making: national mitigation strategies in Western Europe},
        journaltitle = {Climate Policy},
        date = {2014},
        OPTtranslator = {translator},
        OPTannotator = {annotator},
        OPTcommentator = {commentator},
        OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
        OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
        OPTeditor = {editor},
        OPTeditora = {editora},
        OPTeditorb = {editorb},
        OPTeditorc = {editorc},
        OPTjournalsubtitle = {journalsubtitle},
        OPTissuetitle = {issuetitle},
        OPTissuesubtitle = {issuesubtitle},
        OPTlanguage = {language},
        OPToriglanguage = {origlanguage},
        OPTseries = {series},
        volume = {16},
        number = {1},
        OPTeid = {eid},
        OPTissue = {issue},
        OPTmonth = {month},
        pages = {88-108},
        OPTversion = {version},
        OPTnote = {note},
        OPTissn = {issn},
        OPTaddendum = {addendum},
        OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
        OPTdoi = {doi},
        OPTeprint = {eprint},
        OPTeprintclass = {eprintclass},
        OPTeprinttype = {eprinttype},
        OPTurl = {url},
        OPTurldate = {urldate},
    }

    @online{TorontoStar2012,
        author = {Zerbisias, Antonia},
        ALTeditor = {editor},
        title = {Climate change coverage by the media diminishing as Earth continues to heat up},
        date = {2012},
        url = {http://www.thestar.com/news/insight/2012/01/13/climate\_change\_coverage\_by\_the\_media\_diminishing\_as\_earth\_continues\_to\_heat\_up.html},
        OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
        OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
        OPTlanguage = {language},
        OPTversion = {version},
        OPTnote = {note},
        OPTorganization = {organization},
        OPTdate = {date},
        month = {January},
        OPTyear = {year},
        OPTaddendum = {addendum},
        OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
        OPTurldate = {urldate},
    }

    @online{CBC2012,
        author = {{Canadian Broadcasting Corporation}},
        ALTeditor = {editor},
        title = {Sea level rise underestimated, say B.C. scientists},
        date = {2012},
        url = {http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/british-columbia/sea-level-rise-underestimated-say-b-c-scientists-1.1275818},
        OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
        OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
        OPTlanguage = {language},
        OPTversion = {version},
        OPTnote = {note},
        OPTorganization = {organization},
        OPTdate = {date},
        month = {February},
        OPTyear = {year},
        OPTaddendum = {addendum},
        OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
        OPTurldate = {urldate},
    }

    @online{Huffington2015,
        author = {Frej, Willa},
        ALTeditor = {editor},
        title = {Bill Nye: Millennials Care about Climate Change, Conservatives Should Too},
        date = {2015},
        url = {http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/bill-nye-climate-change-millennials\_us\_5641f7c8e4b0b24aee4bb801},
        OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
        OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
        OPTlanguage = {language},
        OPTversion = {version},
        OPTnote = {note},
        organization = {The Huffington Post},
        OPTdate = {date},
        OPTmonth = {month},
        OPTyear = {year},
        OPTaddendum = {addendum},
        OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
        OPTurldate = {urldate},
    }

    @online{Guardian2014,
        author = {Mathiesen, Karl},
        ALTeditor = {editor},
        title = {Brian Cox: scientists giving false sense of debate on climate change},
        date = {2014},
        url = {http://www.theguardian.com/environment/2014/sep/03/brian-cox-scientists-climate-change},
        OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
        OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
        OPTlanguage = {language},
        OPTversion = {version},
        OPTnote = {note},
        organization = {The Guardian},
        OPTdate = {date},
        month = {September},
        OPTyear = {year},
        OPTaddendum = {addendum},
        OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
        OPTurldate = {urldate},
    }

    @online{CBC2015,
        author = {Rogers, Shelagh},
        ALTeditor = {editor},
        title = {David Suzuki on the world we are creating for our grandchildren},
        date = {2015},
        url = {http://www.cbc.ca/radio/thenextchapter/david-suzuki-emily-urquhart-and-jane-urquhart-1.3240041/david-suzuki-on-the-world-we-are-creating-for-our-grandchildren-1.3240044},
        OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
        OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
        OPTlanguage = {language},
        OPTversion = {version},
        OPTnote = {note},
        OPTorganization = {organization},
        OPTdate = {date},
        month = {September},
        OPTyear = {year},
        OPTaddendum = {addendum},
        OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
        OPTurldate = {urldate},
    }

    @online{IdeaCity2015,
        author = {Moore, Patrick},
        editor = {editor},
        title = {Patrick Moore - {The Sensible Environmentalist}},
        date = {2015},
        url = {http://www.ideacityonline.com/video/patrick-moore-the-sensible-environmentalist/},
        OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
        OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
        OPTlanguage = {language},
        OPTversion = {version},
        OPTnote = {note},
        organization = {Moses Znaimer's Idea City Conference},
        OPTdate = {date},
        OPTmonth = {month},
        OPTyear = {year},
        OPTaddendum = {addendum},
        OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
        OPTurldate = {urldate},
    }

    @online{SuzukiGlobe,
        author = {Rockel, Nick},
        ALTeditor = {editor},
        title = {David Suzuki informed Canada's environmental conscience},
        date = {2010},
        url = {http://www.theglobeandmail.com/report-on-business/david-suzuki-informed-canadas-environmental-conscience/article4348511/},
        organization = {The Globe {and} Mail},
        OPTdate = {date},
        month = {November},
        OPTyear = {year},
        OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
        OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
        OPTlanguage = {language},
        OPTversion = {version},
        OPTnote = {note},
        OPTaddendum = {addendum},
        OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
        OPTurldate = {urldate},
    }

    \end{filecontents*}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}

\begin{document}

%Introduction


%Body Paragraphs


%Conclusion


Word Count: (Total word count will go here)

\nocite{*}
\newpage
\onehalfspacing
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: First off, that is a bit long for an mwe (two items, one cited ought to be enough). Are you sure biblatex supports nocite (I haven't checked, it might use a different syntax)

Comment: @daleif: As far as I know `\nocite` is supported

Comment: The `File `paper1.bib' already exists on the system` is warning, nothing more. But the error is at `New York's ....`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I would also have wondered if it wasn't. I don't (currently use biblatex and is not at a computer) , can you get a (simplified) example to work?

Comment: @daleif: Do you mean me? Yes ;-)

Comment: In your MWE one problem is caused by using UTF-8 characters in the `filecontents` environment, but not loading the `filecontents` package. Add `\usepackage{filecontents}` and everything works just fine. Alternatively use the character `'` instead of `’` in `New York University’s John Brademas Center`. Note that your `.bib` entries contain (roughly) ninety percent junk (all the `OPT` fields) that bloats the MWE to no end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

And the *warning* that `paper1.bib` already exists comes from `filecontents`, which is no problem. However, your example with the given bibliography worked fine with `pdflatex` and `xelatex`, too.

Comment: omg ty. Been searching for hours trying to figure out why \nocite{*} wasn't working. Figures it would be something simple!