# \nocite NOT working

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am writing my thesis in which I need one page as my list of publications. This page will be before the (main) chapters begin. So I use \nocite{ref-name} but nothing. Just a blank chapter heading and nothing.

```
%\chapter*{List of Publications}\label{chap:pubs}
%\input{publications.tex}
```

I have tried a lot of possible iterations; shifting the positions etc etc. but to no avail. I even took a look at [tex stackexchange link here about \nocite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290984/nocite-not-working-while-using-biblatex). I already have the \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} in my preamble; hence the need to finally ask this question.

Please help!

Thanks,
Kashif

EDIT: [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97057/including-additional-bibliography-publication-list-in-thesis/97058) is EXACTLY what I need, but nothing yet

Comment: Well, it would be helpful if we knew what `publications.tex` contains...

Comment: It would help us *a lot* if you could tell us more about the bibliography setup in your document. Ideally you would show us a so-called MWE (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), a short example document that tells us what you are doing.

Comment: Note that `\nocite{<key>}` (or `\nocite{*}`) does not produce any output itself. It just tells BibTeX or Biber to add `<key>` (or all entries in the `.bib` file) to the bibliography. You still need to print the bibliography with `\bibliography` or `\printbibliography`. Note that by default you will not get a split bibliography or a separate bibliography containing just your publications.

Comment: \nocite{DBLP:conf/space/KamelSPNSFB16}
\nocite{DBLP:conf/cosade/NawazKSF17}
\nocite{DBLP:conf/ches/BernsteinKLMMN017}
\nocite{DBLP:conf/prime/NawazBSF18}
\nocite{DBLP:conf/ngcas/NawazLSF18}
\nocite{DBLP:journals/integration/NawazBLSF19}

Comment: @moewe yes, so I have \bibliography at the end of my preamble. With this, I am able to have the complete bibliography of my thesis "printed" perfectly well. But in addition to this, I need the above 6 citations to be published in a separate chapter as part of my publications only

Answer (score -1):

[This is THE solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97059/102605)
Note: change the header from article to the specific header you are using (fyi: this is already mentioned)